# BeanShell PostProcessor error Jmeter GUI works, command line doesn't

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

The following code is in a BeanShell PostProcessor works fine when I run a test using Jmeter on GUI mode. If I run it from the command line I get the following exception:

```
015/09/10 18:25:13 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``notFound="NOT_FOUND"; vars.put("AUDIT_CODE",notFound . . . '' : Typed variable declaration 
2015/09/10 18:25:13 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``notFound="NOT_FOUND"; vars.put("AUDIT_CODE",notFound . . . '' : Typed variable declaration
```

Any idea why this could happen?

```
String notFound="NOT_FOUND";
vars.put("AUDIT_CODE",notFound);
String auditCode=vars.get("AUDIT_CODE");
if(auditCode.equals("NOT_FOUND")){
    if (vars.get("AUDITS_RESULT_0")!=null){
        String audit = vars.get("AUDITS_RESULT_0");
        if(audit.contains("WAITING")){
            String[] auditLineWithCode = audit.split("auditCode=");
            String[] auditLineJustWithCode=auditLineWithCode[1].split(",");
            vars.put("AUDIT_CODE",auditLineJustWithCode[0]);
            log.info("AUDIT_CODE:"+vars.get("AUDIT_CODE"));
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
audit = vars.get("AUDITS_RESULT_0");
```

to

```
String audit = vars.get("AUDITS_RESULT_0");
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated the code, that was a bad copy paste. The issue remains the same.

Comment: Try adding `debug();` statement in the very beginning of your script, it will print a ton of debugging information to STDOUT. Another option is surrounding your code in `try {}` block followed by `catch (Exception ex) { log info("ERROR", ex);}` - this way you'll be able to see failure details in *jmeter.log* file. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for comprehensive information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter